# I'm Trying to Download Images from a Website via Scraping but I'm not able to collect them bc they are generated on a Modal

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to use Rvest to go through several pages and download a specific image generated in a modal. These are public documents but are +24,500 documents which are a pain to download by hand.

I've already tried to explore the elements within the webpage using Rvest but got to no good conclusion because I lack skills and knowledge on how to use Rvest here is my code:

```
#Libraries ----
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# this was to loop through the 24585 different pages once I was able to extract the URL for the image and some how save it into disc
for (i in 1:24585){
  Table_Url <- paste0("https://trep.gt/#!/tc1/CAS/e0/m1/1?casId=M",i)
  print(Table_Url)
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

The image is the big yellow JPG generated when we click the ".button--veracta1" I believe the button fires a query which will end up fetching the image

Answer (score 0):

Site data, along with image links, is delivered in a series of JSON files, one per every Departamento. Downloading and parsing those would be the first step.
There are 24 585 records in resulting dataframe which seems about right. From there it's just downloading.

Example bellow stores all files in a single output directory, filenames are constructed by regions / location, you'd probably want to review that and perhaps think through how you'd track and resume download. And download is currently limited to 1 request / s.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(curl)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)

# parse deeply nested json, extract image links and few details
parse_gtm2023 <- function(json_file){
  read_json(json_file) %>% 
    {
      tibble(dep_num  = .$divNum,
             dep_name = .$divName,
             divs     = .$divs)
    } %>% 
    hoist(divs,
          munic_num = "divNum",
          munic_name = "divName",
          "secciones") %>% 
    unnest_longer(secciones) %>% 
    hoist(secciones, "seccion", "casillas") %>%
    unnest_longer(casillas) %>% 
    hoist(casillas, mesa = "mesa", img = list("info", "img")) %>% 
    select(!where(is.list))
}

### collect image data

# local json destination path
json_dir <- file.path("out", "json")
dir.create(json_dir, recursive = TRUE)

# 24 json files, 0..23, one per each Departamento
json_l <- str_glue("https://trep.gt/ext/jsonData_gtm2023/1687736870/1688050101/gtm2023_tc1_e{0:23}.json")

# fetch jsons, store in ./out/json/
h <- new_handle()
walk(json_l, \(json_f) curl_fetch_disk(json_f, file.path(json_dir, basename(json_f)), h), .progress = TRUE)
#> ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 92% | ETA: 3s 

# parse all json files, rbind the list and return single data.frame / tibble
parsed_df <- list.files(json_dir, pattern = "json$", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  map(parse_gtm2023) %>% 
  list_rbind() %>% 
  arrange(mesa)

glimpse(parsed_df)
#> Rows: 24,585
#> Columns: 7
#> $ dep_num    <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,…
#> $ dep_name   <chr> "Distrito Central", "Distrito Central", "Distrito Central",…
#> $ munic_num  <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,…
#> $ munic_name <chr> "Guatemala", "Guatemala", "Guatemala", "Guatemala", "Guatem…
#> $ seccion    <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3,…
#> $ mesa       <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, …
#> $ img        <chr> "d1/1687736870/cdt000101/c508eedb08f26f80296ad5f12b7f8fbd0e…


### image download

# destination path
img_dir <- file.path("out", "img")
dir.create(img_dir, recursive = TRUE)

# helper for pmap / pwalk, function gets all parsed_df variables as paramters and 
# will be called for each parsed_df row, downloads image,
# returns ("status_code", "type", "url", "content") from curl_fetch_disk
fetch_img <- function(dep_num, dep_name, munic_num, munic_name, seccion, mesa, img){
  # 00_01_0001_00001.jpg
  img_fname <- sprintf("%.2d_%.2d_%.4d_%.5d.jpg", dep_num, munic_num, seccion, mesa)
  img_url <- paste0("https://trep.gt/docs/", img)
  curl_fetch_disk(img_url, file.path(img_dir, img_fname), h)[c("status_code", "type", "content", "url")]
}

# limit rate to 1 fetch / s
slow_fetch <- slowly(fetch_img)

# (slowly) fetch first 5 images, report download status
pmap(parsed_df[1:5,], slow_fetch, .progress = TRUE) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  mutate(url = char(url, shorten = "front"),
         content = basename(content) %>% char(shorten = "front"))
#> ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 80% | ETA: 2s
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   status_code type       content              url                               
#>         <int> <chr>      <char>               <char>                            
#> 1         200 image/jpeg 00_01_0001_00001.jpg …df7237aca385b8fc4fbfbf52a26e0.jpg
#> 2         200 image/jpeg 00_01_0001_00002.jpg …bd9f568d1773d67f97ba926dce69b.jpg
#> 3         200 image/jpeg 00_01_0001_00003.jpg …0c9c74d8275b401ddd7fbe8e64ed3.jpg
#> 4         200 image/jpeg 00_01_0001_00004.jpg …673c04e223b211f607091dc37abc5.jpg
#> 5         200 image/jpeg 00_01_0002_00005.jpg …ff00dd469f15e96040e8e1c275a30.jpg

# resulting files:
fs::dir_info(img_dir)[,1:3]
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   path                         type         size
#>   <fs::path>                   <fct> <fs::bytes>
#> 1 out/img/00_01_0001_00001.jpg file         342K
#> 2 out/img/00_01_0001_00002.jpg file         334K
#> 3 out/img/00_01_0001_00003.jpg file         332K
#> 4 out/img/00_01_0001_00004.jpg file         322K
#> 5 out/img/00_01_0002_00005.jpg file         297K
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: ty for this! its great! this is way beyond my skills, I think I'm a very novice R user still, I've been able to work on some R shiny projects but this is way out of my league. What path should I take to develop my skills further? any suggestions? Ty for this! its Awesome!

Comment: Glad it helped. You also have an option to answer as accepted if it was useful for you. If you are interested more in Tidyverse-style R, https://r4ds.hadley.nz/ is a fine and up to date resource, well worth your time.